# How to add ST_GeomFromEWKT in mysql?

Tags: mysql, geoalchemy

I am using geoalchemy2 with mysql database. I have a polygon field. While inserting I am getting this error -

```
from appmain import application
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(application)    
from models import db
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry


class Location(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'location'

        id =                db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        name =              db.Column(db.Unicode)
        polygon =           db.Column(Geometry('POLYGON'))

        def addLocation(self, params):
            self.name = params['name']
            self.polygon = params['polygon']
            db.session.add(self)
            db.session.commit()
            return self
```

Now whenever I am trying to insert a row, I am doing this

```
>>> params=dict()
>>> params['name'] = "North Goa"
>>> params['polygon'] = 'POLYGON((15.347761924346951 73.89541625976562,15.3371671315587 73.88717651367188,15.33319394570966 73.8720703125,15.33319394570966 73.85421752929688,15.33319394570966 73.84048461914062,15.338491510050416 73.82125854492188,15.34511327654474 73.81
301879882812,15.353059119130291 73.79379272460938,15.363653105266007 73.7786865234375,15.378218957375953 73.77182006835938,15.391459757417053 73.76495361328125,15.402051791032589 73.7567138671875,15.419262695070014 73.75396728515625,15.435148417952396 73.74298095703125,
15.458974721921686 73.7347412109375,15.478827882482104 73.72238159179688,15.486768613472801 73.72238159179688,15.500002487463066 73.71826171875,15.519851708918093 73.70864868164062,15.529114025628232 73.70452880859375,15.546314366981463 73.70315551757812,15.566159129772
904 73.7017822265625,15.583356375639625 73.69903564453125,15.605842909610056 73.70452880859375,15.620391706641977 73.707275390625,15.634939470864143 73.71139526367188,15.649486201412108 73.72650146484375,15.657420345721073 73.7457275390625,15.667998725762747 73.75808715
820312,15.666676458207187 73.77593994140625,15.667998725762747 73.79653930664062,15.669320984759295 73.81439208984375,15.669320984759295 73.83087158203125,15.669320984759295 73.84872436523438,15.675932151334582 73.85971069335938,15.67989874853036 73.87619018554688,15.68
2543103837817 73.89129638671875,15.67989874853036 73.90640258789062,15.681220930466825 73.92837524414062,15.67989874853036 73.94760131835938,15.673287710388593 73.96408081054688,15.658742673171389 73.98605346679688,15.646841418236296 74.00665283203125,15.640229310707545
 74.02175903320312,15.621714273353259 74.03274536132812,15.59658404687789 74.04373168945312,15.580710739162123 74.05059814453125,15.555575494395464 74.05746459960938,15.537052823106482 74.06707763671875,15.52382132415256 74.07257080078125,15.511912249339868 74.072570800
78125,15.490738864633405 74.0753173828125,15.469563311134118 74.0753173828125,15.452356578816282 74.0753173828125,15.424558071072397 74.06295776367188,15.404699715168281 74.0478515625,15.388811664771108 74.03823852539062,15.36762571133357 74.02175903320312,15.3623288864
24285 74.01351928710938,15.35173483303873 74.00527954101562,15.338491510050416 73.98330688476562,15.330545113171928 73.95721435546875,15.330545113171928 73.93386840820312,15.330545113171928 73.91464233398438, 15.347761924346951 73.89541625976562))'

>>> loc = Location()
>>> loc.addLocation(params)
```

(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1305, 'FUNCTION db_name.ST_GeomFromEWKT does not exist')

MySql server version - 5.5.46

Comment: Can you please add some minimal code to demonstrate what you are doing in context?

Comment: There you go !!

Comment: Old post but for information, Geoalchemy2 doesn't support MySQL : https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy2/issues/109